# Saving 'DATETIME' as 'TIMESTAMP' in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project, that use `LocalDateTime` variables and use a `MySQL` database. I want those variables to be saved in the database as a `TIMESTAMP`, I have tried to use the `LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter` class, but it is only saving them as `DATETIME`.

how can I save `DateTime` as type `Timestamp` in the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Entity
        public class MyEntity
        {    

         // other properties

         @Column
         @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
         private LocalDateTime dateTime;

        }


       @Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {
  @Override
  public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(localDateTime)
        .map(Timestamp::valueOf)
        .orElse(null);
  }
  @Override
  public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(timestamp)
        .map(Timestamp::toLocalDateTime)
        .orElse(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already using that converter and its still only saving the LocalDateTime as type DATETIME, I want it to save in the database as 'TIMESTAMP'

Comment: I tried this and its still saving to the database as DateTime

Comment: what datatype you have set for the column in the database

Comment: '@Column(name = "end", nullable = false)
 private LocalDateTime end; '
That is what I've used

Comment: please ensure column data type is set as TIMESTAMP in the mysql table

Answer (score 0):

Try using like below.

`@Column(name="timestamp", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")`

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this annotation on the property

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```